# Higher order deformations of subvarieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over a field $k$. We know that the deformations of $X$ over $k[t]/(t^2)$ are parametrized by $H^1(X,T_X)$; given such a deformation, we know that it can be extended over $k[t]/(t^3)$ if and only if the corresponding element $\xi \in H^1(X,T_X)$ satisfies $q(\xi )=0$, where $q:H^1(X,T_X)\otimes H^1(X,T_X)\rightarrow H^2(X,T_X)$ is the cup-product deduced from the Lie bracket on $T_X$.

Now consider a closed subvariety $Y\subset X$, say smooth. Again, we know that the deformations of $Y$ inside $X$ over $k[t]/(t^2)$ are parametrized by $H^0(Y, N_{Y/X})$ (the normal bundle of $Y$ in $X$). Given such a deformation, how can we express that it extends to over $k[t]/(t^3)$? What would be the analogue of the map $q$?

Comment: Often you can apply the logic from the first paragraph to the second paragraph by replacing $X$ by the blowing up of $X$ along $Y$.

Comment: Are you not essentially asking about a Lie algebroid structure on $N_{Y/X}[-1]=T_{Y/X}$? This has been studied in https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.5260.

Comment: I imagine that you want to first fix a deformation of the ambient $X$ to $k[t]/(t^3)$? If yes, then shouldn't the class of this deformation come into play?

Comment: ... oh I see, you want to consider the trivial deformation of $X$.

Comment: @Pavel Safronov: Many thanks, the paper you quote looks quite relevant. I will read it.

Comment: You might be interested in this paper of Manetti: http://www.numdam.org/item/ASNSP_2007_5_6_4_631_0

Comment: @Brent Pym: Sounds also quite relevant, thanks!